# External monitor stopped working

Tags: windows, drivers

my external monitor stopped working today after restart. I found the computer on during the night. Running win 10 64b on Lenovo U430p.

The monitor worked fine the whole time. I can see windows logo while booting, but then it says no signal. When I uninstalled the video driver it worked (login screen, desktop, res 800*600), until windows installed driver over it. I tried getting newest driver from both Lenovo and Intel, but with no results.

Did anyone experience this issue as well? I read about people having this with new computer but not to happen from the blue and ususally at least disabling the video adapter helped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found real solution and it seems to be a problem of Intel graphic cards.

However reverting to most basic driver windows can offer did the trick

- Uninstall driver
- Rollback driver
- Using wushowhide.diagcab utility (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) disable updates for all video card drivers